# What is a 'Sha-Touched' socket?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Looking through some of the forth coming gear available from the later tiers in Mists of Pandaria, I have noticed that on the item "Kri-tak, Imperial Scepter of the Swarm" has a socket on called simply "Sha-Touched".

I am assuming this is a socket since it appears listed on the item as you'd normally expect a gem socket to appear:

[image: Kri-tak, Imperial Scepter of the Swarm]

What is a 'Sha-Touched' socket? What do I put in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a socket for the Legendary gem you can get by completing the [legendary chain quest](http://www.wowhead.com/news=205336/mists-of-pandaria-legendary-weapons-preview).

- [500 Str gem](http://www.wowhead.com/item=89881)
- [500 Int gem](http://www.wowhead.com/item=89882)
- [500 Agi gem](http://www.wowhead.com/item=89873)